# How to insert the profile_pic and signature in the db in codeigniter?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-4

//This is my view file

i need to insert the data into the database using the form but whole data is inserting into the database but the pic and signature is not inserting into the db how to insert the profile pic and signature into the database plz anyone can help me  to get this tasks done in codeigniter

```
   <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="profile">Profile Picture</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="profile" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="signature">Signature</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="signature" />
                        </div>
```

> Blockquote<?php

```
**//I wrote the logic like this but anyone modify this give me the correct code to complete this task**

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\UserModel;
use CodeIgniter\Services;

class AddNewUserController extends BaseController
{
    public function add()
    {
        return view('addnew');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        if ($this->request->getMethod() === 'post') {
            $config = array(
                'file_name' => time(),
                'overwrite' => TRUE,
                'max_width' => '1028',
                'max_height' => '800',
                'max_size' => '24000000',
                'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg',
                'upload_path' => 'public/images'
            );

            $upload = Services::upload($config); // Load the Upload service

            if ($upload->do_upload('profile')) {
                $profileData = $upload->getData();
                $profilePath = 'public/images/' . $profileData['file_name'];
            } else {
                echo $upload->getErrorString();
                return;
            }

            if ($upload->do_upload('signature')) {
                $signatureData = $upload->getData();
                $signaturePath = 'public/images/' . $signatureData['file_name'];
            } else {
                echo $upload->getErrorString();
                return;
            }

            // Retrieve form input data
            $name = $this->request->getPost('name');
            $email = $this->request->getPost('email');
            $phone = $this->request->getPost('phone');
            $role = $this->request->getPost('role');
            $address = $this->request->getPost('address');
            $gender = $this->request->getPost('gender');
            $dob = $this->request->getPost('dob');
            $password = $this->request->getPost('password');

            // Create a new instance of UserModel
            $userModel = new UserModel();

            // Prepare the data for insertion
            $data = [
                'name' => $name,
                'email' => $email,
                'phone_no' => $phone,
                'role' => $role,
                'address' => $address,
                'gender' => $gender,
                'date_of_birth' => $dob,
                'profile_pic' => file_get_contents($profilePath), // Store the binary data of the image
                'signature' => file_get_contents($signaturePath), // Store the binary data of the image
                'password' => password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), // Hash the password for security
            ];

            // Insert the data into the database
            $userModel->insert($data);

            // Redirect to a success page or perform other actions as needed
            return redirect()->to('/');
        }
    }
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: is this correct code to insert the image in the db

Comment: You should not store the picture data itself in the database. You already store the pictures on the public/images folder. So instead of doing `file_get_contents`,  you should just store the path to the file in the database.